# Cannot see a Custom Block in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm trying to create some blocks with custom content in Drupal 7, but I cannot see them anywhere (Structure>Blocks)

- I'm using Drupal 7
- I have **successfully activated the module**
- Cache is not activated

Here is the code:

**bcndevcon.info**

```
; $Id: bcndevcon.info,v 1.0.0.0 2011/02/09 10:11:15 BcnDevCon Exp $
name = "Custom BcnDevCon Modules"
description = "Custom BcnDevCon Modules In Code"
core = "7.x"
package = "Custom BcnDevCon Modules"
```

**bcndevcon.module**

```
<?php

function bcndevcon_blocks_info() {
    $blocks['my_custom_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('Custom Block Name'),
    );

    $blocks['my_custom_block2'] = array(
        'info' => t('Custom Block Name 2'),
    );

    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view().
 */
function bcndevcon_blocks_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_custom_block':
      $block['subject'] = t('Custom Block Name');
      $block['content'] = bcndevcon_contents();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * custom html block
 * @return string
 */
function bcndevcon_contents() {
  return '
    </p><div class="body">
      Hello World, this is a example custom Block
    </div><p>
  ';
}

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A detail blog: http://goo.gl/kD3TZu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is a typo just in the question... but you have your hooks defined as `hook_blocks_*` with an extra `s` at the end of the word `block` which shouldn't be there.